# Union Select and Group Occurrences

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a problem setting up my Query

```
(SELECT * FROM attendance WHERE am_slip="absent" AND pm_slip="none")
 UNION
(SELECT * FROM attendance WHERE am_slip="none" AND pm_slip="absent")
 UNION
(SELECT * FROM attendance WHERE am_slip="absent" AND pm_slip IS NULL)
 UNION
(SELECT * FROM attendance WHERE am_slip="absent" AND pm_slip="late")
 UNION
(SELECT * FROM attendance WHERE am_slip="late" AND pm_slip="absent")
 UNION
(SELECT * FROM attendance WHERE am_slip="absent" AND pm_slip="absent")
```

I want to Combine/merge all Occurrences in data table (ID Number) but I can't make it. So, can u help me?

This is the output using the query above:

[image]

This is the output I want:

[image]
to
[image]

This is the Table, I want to merge them and show single output:
[image]

Experimental Query But Not working:

> SELECT stu_id, COUNT(*) AS id_count from (SELECT * FROM attendance WHERE am_slip="late" AND pm_slip="none")
>                                         UNION
>                                         (SELECT * FROM attendance WHERE am_slip="none" AND pm_slip="late")
>                                         UNION
>                                         (SELECT * FROM attendance WHERE am_slip="late" AND pm_slip IS NULL)
>                                         UNION
>                                         (SELECT * FROM attendance WHERE am_slip="late" AND pm_slip="absent")
>                                         UNION
>                                         (SELECT * FROM attendance WHERE am_slip="absent" AND pm_slip="late")
>                                         UNION
>                                         (SELECT * FROM attendance WHERE am_slip="late" AND pm_slip="late")
>                 GROUP BY stu_id
>           ORDER BY id_count

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2990/minimal-complete-and-verifiable-example)

Comment: updated the question

Comment: Please, can you give the complete structure of the tables that are involucrated with your query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want a distinct result you correctly use UNION but in this case you should avoid the select * (select all columns), you should select the column involved  explicatally

```
SELECT name, ID_No, Num_Absence, Handle 
FROM attendance WHERE am_slip="absent" AND pm_slip="none")
  UNION
SELECT name, ID_No, Num_Absence, Handle 
FROM attendance WHERE am_slip="none" AND pm_slip="absent"
  UNION
SELECT name, ID_No, Num_Absence, Handle 
FROM attendance WHERE am_slip="absent" AND pm_slip IS NULL
  UNION
SELECT name, ID_No, Num_Absence, Handle 
FROM attendance WHERE am_slip="absent" AND pm_slip="late"
  UNION
SELECT name, ID_No, Num_Absence, Handle 
FROM attendance WHERE am_slip="late" AND pm_slip="absent"
  UNION
SELECT name, ID_No, Num_Absence, Handle 
FROM attendance WHERE am_slip="absent" AND pm_slip="absent"
```

Comment: your code  sample is not coherent  with the image ,, add  your real table schema  ..  and avoid the  `*`  . show the column name   instead

Answer (score 0):

Ill give you and example using DISTINCT and replacing all UNION clauses by using the ORs operand on the WHERE clause:

```
SELECT
    DISTINCT name, ID_No, Num_Absence, Handle 
FROM
    attendance
WHERE
    (am_slip="absent" AND (pm_slip="none" OR pm_slip IS NULL OR pm_slip="late" OR pm_slip="absent"))
OR
    (am_slip="none" AND pm_slip="absent")
OR
    (am_slip="late" AND pm_slip="absent")
```

Answer (score 0):

done Thank you guys for helping me out

> SELECT idnum.stu_id, COUNT(*) from (SELECT * FROM attendance WHERE am_slip="absent" AND pm_slip="none"
>                                         UNION ALL
>                                         SELECT * FROM attendance WHERE am_slip="none" AND pm_slip="absent"
>                                         UNION ALL
>                                         SELECT * FROM attendance WHERE am_slip="absent" AND pm_slip IS NULL
>                                         UNION ALL
>                                         SELECT * FROM attendance WHERE am_slip="absent" AND pm_slip="late"
>                                         UNION ALL
>                                         SELECT * FROM attendance WHERE am_slip="late" AND pm_slip="absent"
>                                         UNION ALL
>                                         SELECT * FROM attendance WHERE am_slip="absent" AND pm_slip="absent") as idnum
>       GROUP BY stu_id
>           ORDER BY stu_id